# Google Foobar verification bug

Tags: google-chrome

I may have encountered a bug within the code verification process in Google's Foobar Challenge. I am on the last challenge called disorderly escape with a few days on the clock.

None of the test cases are passing, even if I directly return just the expected values of the test cases. So if the first test case's expected value is 7, and I return 7 on the first line that is run, then it should pass that test case.

However, still none of them pass.

This method has worked in past challenges and I have attempted to pass test cases using full solution code as well.

I've emailed foobar-help@google.com and left feedback on foobar using the 'feedback' command, but haven't received a reply for more than 10 days.

Is there something that I am missing? Has anyone encountered something similar?

(can't find the right tag for this :/)

Comment: This seemed to be a problem with just the disorderly-escape problem. The returned value needed to be a string value so when i tried with return "7" instead of return 7, it started working